# Getting an auto increment variable for a join query in aws aurora mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a select query like this:

```
select @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank,
        a.name,a.count as ad,c.count as m_count, (a.count/c.count) as ratio 
from (SELECT @rownum := 0) r, Batch a, nsCount c 
WHERE a.name=c.name 
ORDER BY ratio DESC;
```

The idea is that since the results will be sorted by ratio, each row will have a column called as rank with the first row havign the highest ratio having rank 1 and so forth. But this is not how the above query is turning out to be and the first row has 2610 rank and the next row 23000 . How do I fix this?

Comment: Do the filtering and joinin in a s ubquery and do the numbering in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write this query is:

```
select row_number() over (order by a.count/c.count desc) as seqnum,
       b.name, b.count as ad, c.count as m_count, 
       (a.count/c.count) as ratio 
from Batch b join
     nsCount c 
     on b.name = c.name 
order by ratio desc;
```

Note:

- The query uses meaningful table aliases.
- The query uses proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- `row_number()` is the best way to do what you want.

In order versions of MySQL, you need to use variables.  This often requires a subquery for ordering:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1), bc.*
from (select b.name, b.count as ad, c.count as m_count, 
           (a.count/c.count) as ratio 
      from Batch b join
           nsCount c 
           on b.name = c.name 
      order by ratio desc
     ) bc cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
```